# MultiBinding on Value Changed

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, datagrid, converters

I have a `MultiBinding` on a `DataGrid`´s `CellStyle` property which calls a converter.

```
<Setter Property="CellStyle">
  <Setter.Value>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
      <Setter Property="Background">
        <Setter.Value>
          <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource TheConverter}">
            <MultiBinding.Bindings>
               <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}"/>
               <Binding Path="SpecificColorList" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource AncestorType=local:BADataGrid}" Mode="OneWay"/>
            </MultiBinding.Bindings>
          </MultiBinding>
        </Setter.Value>
      </Setter>
    </Style>
  </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
```

When I initialize the `DataGrid`´s source (`ObservableCollection`) the converter is called for every single cell (of course...).
Now I want additional to that, that the converter is called every time a cell´s value changes. How can I achieve this?